# Getting difficulty in adding CheckBox Dynamically

Tags: android, checkbox

I want to create the checkbox dynamically in the following code.The checkbox is getting displayed fine,but it is not showing the text associated with it which added through setText().This is where i am calling the method:

```
ArrayList<String> FilesInFolder = GetFiles(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+File.separator+"Naseeb"
,getApplicationContext());
```

This is the code:

```
public static ArrayList<String> GetFiles(String DirectoryPath,Context context)
    {
        try
        {
            MyFiles = new ArrayList<String>();
            File f = new File(DirectoryPath);

            boolean checker = SdCardManager.CheckIsFileExists(f);
            if(!checker)
            {
                Toast.makeText(context,"there is some problem in creating File f in GetFiles() method in " +
                        "ShowTheFolderrsInSdCard.java"
                        ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();    
            }
            Toast.makeText(context,f.getAbsolutePath(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            File[] files = f.listFiles();
            if (files.length == 0)
                return null;
            else {
                for (int i=0; i<files.length; i++)
                {
                    CheckBox cbi = new CheckBox(context);
                //  cbi.setText(files[i].getName());
                    cbi.setText("hello");
                    ll.addView(cbi);
                }
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("");
        }
        return MyFiles;
    }
```

Please help me.Thanks in advance.

Comment: As per youd posted code, Are you not getting the all checkbox with "hello" text?

Comment: No,i am only getting the checkbox without text.

Comment: Try to change the color of the checkbox. May be color is matching with your current theme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the background color like

```
cbi.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
```

Refer the following link to add the view dynamically .

[Adding views programatically](http://www.mysamplecode.com/2011/10/android-programmatically-generate.html)

Comment: Set the background color like cbi.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);